# AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword causes .NET console app to crash

Tags: c#, azure, graph

I am attempting to aquiring a MS graph-token for my .NET console application, using this description https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication.
However, when the code goes through the clause right underneath "// Select Account", it just exits. No error message, no nothing. Username and password is correct.

That part of the code used to be the "AcquireTokenInteractive" method, that in turn would open a GUI where users could sign into their Microsoft account. But I do not want that prompt, or any prompt at all.

```
        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            try
            {
                // Select account
                authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, "my_user@dsbintranet.onmicrosoft.com", graphPassword)
                     .ExecuteAsync();

            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Either the account has MFA enabled or you need consent.  To handle  `MsalUiRequiredException`  you need to use `AcquireTokenInteractive`. The `UiRequired` in the ExeptionName clearly says that... https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/exceptions#msaluirequiredexception

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar I am specifically attempting to NOT use MFA, UI, "AcquireTokenInteractive" or anything else that requires a user action for the app to run. Thats why I am using the "AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword" method

Comment: I clearly understand you don't want to use any of those. But if MFA is enabled for your `firstAccount` you cannot bypass the Security feature. Having said that if the username & password is different than the first account and doesn't have MFA enabled it should work.  Try cathing all different Exceptions mentioned in the article  or the  `Exception` instead of `MsalException `

Comment: If you found out the solution do post the answer so that it is helpful to others.

Comment: I will, when I do

Answer (score 0):

Console apps do not support async call which end up as async void event handler or are returned as a Task to your framework.

In your `public static void Main(string[] args)` you can either wait on your async function

```
static void Main()
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }
```

Or you can use

```
static void Main()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync());
}
```

**Edit:** as of Visual studio 2017 you can use `static async Task Main(string[] args)` which will solve the problem

which is a part of Nito.AsyncEx nuget package explained in this blog https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html